# How to measure both before and after byte size and time to compress

Tags: go, compression

I want to gzip a string (it is actually a JSON response)

```
var b bytes.Buffer
gz := gzip.NewWriter(&b)
if _, err := gz.Write([]byte("YourDataHere")); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

How can I easily output the size of bytes before and after compression and more importantly how can I time it takes to compress and decompress back to a string?

Comment: b.Len() will return the number of bytes after compression. len([]byte("YourDataHere")) returns the input data (uncompressed) length. Also "n, err := gz.Write([]byte("YourDataHere"))" will set n as the number of bytes sent to gzip writer (i.e. size of input)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the size as per Nipun Talukdar's comment.

`len([]byte("YourDataHere"))
b.Len()`

And use `time.Now()` and `time.Since()` to get the time taken.

```
var b bytes.Buffer
input := []byte("YourDataHere")

fmt.Println("Input size : ", len(input))

gz := gzip.NewWriter(&b)


start := time.Now() 

gz.Write(input)
if _, err := gz.Flush(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
}


totalTime := time.Since(start) 

fmt.Println("Compressed size : ", b.Len(), "\nTime taken : ", totalTime)
gz.Close()
```

Same method can be applied with unzipping. 
You can also create a support function that can do the timing.

```
func timer(startTime time.Time) {

totalTime := time.Since(startTime)
log.Println("Time taken : ",totalTime)

}
```

Usage : `defer timer(time.Now())` at the start of the function.

Comment: We should do a gz.Flush() before getting the time taken and size of output.

Answer (score 0):

There are examples of how to do this in Go here

https://golang.org/test/bench/go1/gzip_test.go

Thankfully it's BSD licensed...

```
// Copyright 2011 The Go Authors.  All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style
// license that can be found in the LICENSE file.

// This benchmark tests gzip and gunzip performance.

package go1 

import (
  "bytes"
  gz "compress/gzip"
  "io"
  "io/ioutil"
  "testing"
)

var (
  jsongunz = bytes.Repeat(jsonbytes, 10) 
  jsongz   []byte
)

func init() {
  var buf bytes.Buffer
  c := gz.NewWriter(&buf)
  c.Write(jsongunz)
  c.Close()
  jsongz = buf.Bytes()
}

func gzip() {
  c := gz.NewWriter(ioutil.Discard)
  if _, err := c.Write(jsongunz); err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  if err := c.Close(); err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
}

func gunzip() {
  r, err := gz.NewReader(bytes.NewBuffer(jsongz))
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  if _, err := io.Copy(ioutil.Discard, r); err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
  r.Close()
}

func BenchmarkGzip(b *testing.B) {
  b.SetBytes(int64(len(jsongunz)))
  for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
    gzip()
  }
}

func BenchmarkGunzip(b *testing.B) {
  b.SetBytes(int64(len(jsongunz)))
  for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
    gunzip()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's unfortunate that `gzip.Writer` can't report the number of compressed bytes written to the underlying stream.  It gets more complicated when that underlying stream is not in-memory.

To solve this, I wrote a "counting `io.Writer`" that I place in between `gzip.Writer` and the underlying stream, so I can count and extract the number of compressed bytes written.

Try out the following code in the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Scqw5iidQqK).

```golang
package main

import (
    "compress/gzip"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
)

// countingWriter is an io.Writer that counts the total bytes written to it.
type countingWriter struct {
    w     io.Writer
    Count int
}

var _ io.Writer = &countingWriter{}

func newCountingWriter(w io.Writer) *countingWriter {
    return &countingWriter{w: w}
}

func (cw *countingWriter) Write(p []byte) (int, error) {
    n, err := cw.w.Write(p)
    cw.Count += n
    return n, err
}

func ExampleUse(w io.Writer) (int, error) {
    cw := newCountingWriter(w)
    zw, err := gzip.NewWriterLevel(cw, gzip.BestCompression)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }

    if _, err := zw.Write([]byte("hello world")); err != nil {
        return cw.Count, err
    }

    err = zw.Close()
    return cw.Count, err
}

func main() {
    n, err := ExampleUse(os.Stderr)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("wrote %d bytes\n", n)
}
```

Comment: a warning should be added to alert that to get the total size of written gzip bytes, one must Close the gzip writer so the data is flushed. Otherwise this conts only the numbers of bytes after compression. OP wanted to know compressed and uncompressed bytes length.

Comment: I would write a statswriter to get all of `time taken + bytes compressed + bytes uncompressed`